# vagrant customize VM after provisioning

Tags: vagrant

is it possible to customize the VM after it has been provisioned? I know you can execute things like:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize "post-boot", ["controlvm", :id, "nic1", "hostonly", "vboxnet0"]
end
```

But that is executed before provisioning the machine. What I want to do is:

1. Create the VM. The VM is actually a virtual appliance.
2. Provision the VM.
3. Reconfigure eth0 to be of type host-net instead of NAT.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [vagrant book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/vagrant-up-and/9781449336103/ch04.html)

> With VirtualBox, Vagrant requires the first network device attached to
>   the virtual machine to be a NAT device. The NAT device is used for
>   port forwarding, which is how Vagrant gets SSH access to the virtual
>   machine.
>
> Therefore, any host-only or bridged networks will be added as
>   additional network devices and exposed to the virtual machine as
>   “eth1,” “eth2,” and so on. “eth0” or “en0” is generally always the NAT
>   device.
>
> It isn’t currently possible to override this requirement, but it is
>   important to understand that it is in place.

If you need to change, you'll need to change in virtual box directly

Comment: I know, it's needed to do "vagrant ssh". But I don't care about that to be honest. Changing the nic manually works but I was wondering if I can automate that process. I can change the nic before the provisioning step but I would like to do it later.

Comment: you can have a look to [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) to run a your script after vagrant command